# How to detect implicit HTML option selection with JQuery (or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a block of markup like this:

```
<select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

the default value will be "volvo" even though there is not a selected="selected" property on any option.

Is there a way to tell if the value is derived through an explicit selected property versus the default implicit value?

If so, what is the necessary Javascript or JQuery code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check for selected attribute:

```
if(!$('select').find('option[selected]').length)
    alert('default option');
```

Comment: For some reason my initial attempts to detect the selected property failed, but this is what I was looking for.  I was not looking for anything triggered by a change event.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $changed;
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $changed = true;
});
if($changed){
    //manual selection event
}else{
    //nope, it's default
}
```

Or, just add `<option> ---- Choose ---- </option>` and avoid that unnecessary code.

Comment: you missed a $ in if condition `if($changed)` ..:)

Comment: @roasted .. you should remove your "maybe" :) :) .. there is no doubt in it.. :p

Comment: The change event does not trigger when you choose the already selected value, which will cause issues. Better always use a preselected option with no value, maybe one that can't be re-selected.

Comment: @RenéGeuze Not sure if I understand the reason for your comment. I'm quite aware of how it works and even supplied the line `<option> ---- Choose --- </option>` to be the default value instead of `volvo` as it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get the question but `volvo` is selected by default because of how HTML works.

You can use Ohgodwhy suggestion for a "blank" option.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAdas/)